# わからない vs わかね in My Boss My Hero

Tags: colloquial-language, spoken-language, anime

I was watching My Boss My Hero, and I could have sworn he said わかね instead of わからない. Is this feasible? Is there some dialect that drops off ない for ね?

Comment: Could you write the whole phrase as an example?

Comment: This happens a lot in anime & manga. It makes a (usually male) character sound more masculine, tough, flippant, or gangsta'. The main character in My Boss My Hero is from a Yakuza family, so this style of speech establishes his background.

Answer (score 14):

It's fairly common for both `ai` and `ae` to be slurred to `ee` in colloquial speech.

For example:

- じゃない　→　じゃねぇ　　　`janai → janee`
- のみたい　→　のみてぇ　　　`nomitai → nomitee`
- おまえ　　→　おめぇ　　　　`omae → omee`
- てまえ　　→　てめぇ　　　　`temae → temee`

Your example has an additional contraction.  When a vowel is dropped between `r` and `n`, you end up with `rn`.  This isn't pronounceable, so it assimilates to `nn`.

- わからない　→　わかんない　　　`wakaranai → *wakarnai → wakaNnai`

Then this undergoes the other contraction we already talked about:

- わかんない　→　わかんねぇ　　　`wakaNnai → wakaNnee`

Japanese is somewhat sensitive to length, so that `ん` doesn't drop out very easily, and the vowel at the end tends to stay long.  It's possible that they *were* both shortened, but without hearing it, my guess is that it was `わかんねぇ` and not `わかね`.

As for *where* this happens, I have to admit I'm no expert on dialects.  But as I understand it, it's fairly widespread.  I've read that it happens in and around Tōkyō, and I know it happens in other parts of the Kantō area as well.  To be honest, I wouldn't be surprised if it happened all over Japan.  (But the charts I found only mentioned the Kantō area.)

Answer (score 1):

Changing ない to ね is routine in several dialects. So you'll hear things like 知らね instead of 知らない, or やらね instead of やらない.

Additionally, the character probably said わかんね, not わかね. ら and る will sometimes be rendered as ん when followed by  な行 mora such as な, ね, or の. So you'll hear things like つまんね (instead of つまらない - つまんない is, of course, also used), どうすんの (どうするの), or なにしてんの (なにしてるの).

Comment: It's not really a dialect. More like casual male speech thing.

Comment: It is a dialectal feature, especially in the various Tohoku dialects. 

But you are correct in saying that in some areas, it's a masculine speech pattern.