# What does きた mean in this context?

Tags: meaning

So I was watching an anime where one of the characters was making food for another. The person cooking food for the other person said that some of his snot dripped into the food, and the guy responded with きたね！ The subtitles translated it as, "That's gross!" But I don't how it could be translated like that...can anyone help me out? Is きた the past tense of a verb, or is it just a noun or something like that?

Comment: `ai`-to-`ee` sound change is described [here](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/13073/5010). Additionally the last long vowel is shortened in your example.

Answer (score 1):

きたね is the vulgar/rude/cool way of saying きたない(汚い).
Which means dirty.

Most of the i adjective can converted as such. It is usually used by boys.

すごい -> すげ(cool)
たかい -> たけ(tall)
ない -> ね(none)

Comment: Note that this is more a kanto (Tokyo region) thing. They don't use this in Kansai (Osaka region).

Comment: "vulgar/rude/cool" does not really explain this phonetic phenomenon.