# Grammar behind 届けねえとなんねえな

Tags: grammar

> んじゃあ、生きのいいうちに届けねえとなんねえな

Context: an employee which seems to deliver something for a store.

My take on the first half is: Well, (if I don't deliver/I have to deliver) it while I'm still full of vigor/energy...

What's with the なんねえな part? I can't get anything out of it apart from the な at the end.

Comment: `while I'm still full of vigor/energy` ← You sure the subject of 生きのいい is "I", not the thing that's delivered? Like, "while it's still fresh". 普通、自分のことを「生きがいい」とは言わないので。

Comment: @Chocolate I see, I guessed it was the other meaning because what he carried didn't look like food or the like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 届けねえとなんねえな

It's a colloquial, contracted pronunciation of...

> 届けないとならないな

which means "have to deliver".

ない ⇒ ねえ
ならない ⇒ なんねえ

Related threads:

- [What is じゃねぇか? What is its original form?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/18454/9831)
- [わからない vs わかね in My Boss My Hero](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/13069/9831)

As you may know, 「～ないとならない」 means "have to" "must". (≈「～なければならない」「～ないといけない」)

Comment: Thank you very much!